# How to differentiate two versions of an API method in Swagger documentation?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have 2 versions of an API GET method, and I need to add swagger documentation for both versions so that the Swagger UI can show up these two versions clearly. And I need to have **same path URL** for both versions of GET. Path URL for both GET endpoints is

```
/maintenance/exec/book/{id}
```

The only difference between two versions is in V1, the path parameter is bookId and in V2, the path parameter is bookRefId

Currently I have added the Swagger documentation for both versions, but in the Swagger UI, I could able to find only the V2 GET url. Suggest me a way to explicitly add the version of the GET method (V1 and V2) in this API in Swagger docs

```
 @GET
 @Path( "{" + ID_PARAM + "}" )
 @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
 @Operation( summary = "Get Book" )
 @ApiResponse( responseCode = "200", description = "The requested book.",
     content = @Content( mediaType = "application/json",
           schema = @Schema( implementation = BookGet.class ) ) )
 @ApiResponse( responseCode = "404",
     description = "The requested book cannot be found." )
 Book get( @Parameter( in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = ID_PARAM, required = true,
     description = "The unique identifier for the book resource.",
     schema = @Schema( type = "string" )) @PathParam( ID_PARAM ) String bookId)
     throws NotFoundException;

 @GET
 @Path( "{" + ID_PARAM + "}" )
 @Produces( ApiMediaType.API_V2_TYPE )
 @Operation( summary = "Get Book V2" )
 @ApiResponse( responseCode = "200", description = "The requested book V2.",
     content = @Content( mediaType = "application/vnd.yes.httapi.v2+json",
           schema = @Schema( implementation = BookV2Get.class ) ) )
 @ApiResponse( responseCode = "404",
     description = "The requested book resource cannot be found." )
 BookV2 getV2( @Parameter( in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = ID_PARAM, required = true,
     description = "The unique identifier for the book resource.",
     schema = @Schema( type = "string" ) ) @PathParam( ID_PARAM ) String refId )
     throws NotFoundException;
```

Comment: are you looking for something like here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287298/write-swagger-doc-that-consumes-multiple-content-types-e-g-application-json-and

Comment: This might also help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is not possible with Swagger .

You need to differentiate using `"/v1/getBook"` and `"/v2/getBook"` .

> ### Swagger Documentation

> OpenAPI defines a unique operation as a combination of a path and an HTTP method. This means that two GET or two POST methods for the same path are not allowed – even if they have different parameters (parameters have no effect on uniqueness).

You can find the detailed answer in the official documentation

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/